# "TypeError: listOfTours.map is not a function" while trying to display fetched data in react

Tags: reactjs, axios, use-effect

I'm struggling since two days on this and afters hours of trial and error I couldn't solve it.

What I'm trying to achieve is that I can display my fetched data, which I get from my backend. I saw several example on different websites, but I can't get it to work.

Here is my code and the error I get:

```
function Tours({ isAuth: isAuth, component: Component, ...rest }) {
  const [listOfTours, setListOfTours] = useState([]);
  console.log(listOfTours);

  const getAllTours = () =>
    axios
      .get("/api/all-tours", {
        headers: {
          "x-access-token": localStorage.getItem("token"),
        },
      })
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.data.status === "error") {
          console.log(response.data.status);
        } else {
          setListOfTours(response.data);
        }
      });

  useEffect(() => {
    getAllTours();
  }, []);

  if (listOfTours.length > 0) {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="tourDisplay">
          {listOfTours.map((tour) => {
            return (
              <div>
                <div>Tourname: {tour.tour_name}</div>
                <div>...other values</div>
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>Loading...</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(Tours);
```

```
TypeError: listOfTours.map is not a function
Tours
src/components/tours.js:32
  29 | if (listOfTours.length > 0) {
  30 |   return (
  31 |     <div>
> 32 |       <div className="tourDisplay">
     | ^  33 |         {listOfTours.map((tour) => {
  34 |           return (
  35 |             <div>
```

I think it has something to do with the asynchronous call and that .map can't process with empty array. Therefor, I use the if statement in front of the return, but it also won't work.

Does someone have any idea, or am I missing something?

Comment: It seems `response.data` has a property called `status`, which means it is an object and not an array. When you call `setListOfTours(response.data)`, you will try to `map` over that object, which can't be done. What does your `response` look like?

Comment: What does the response.data look like if you console log inside `.then((response) => {`?

Comment: when you console.log() are you sure `response.data` is array?

Comment: @AndréKrosby the response looks like: https://pastebin.com/sQwu3m4X

Comment: @hotcakedev the response.data looks like: https://pastebin.com/Ft11q7iF

Comment: @callmenikk https://pastebin.com/Ft11q7iF looks like an Array for me. But I could be wrong.

Comment: try `setListOfTours(response.data.data);`

Comment: @AndréKrosby console.log(response.data.data) says undefined

Comment: @Broump, Junko's answer seems correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to make the `getAllTours` function as a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

```
...
const [listOfTours, setListOfTours] = useState(null);

const getAllTours = async () => {
  try {
    // not sure if /api/all-tours is the proper API source
    const tours = await axios.get("/api/all-tours", {
        headers: {
          "x-access-token": localStorage.getItem("token"),
        },
    });

    // try to console.log here to make sure if the tours has responded successfully and what type of the tours.response.data has either object or array
    console.log(tours.response);
    console.log(typeof tours.response.data);

    // this seems to be tours.response without data
    if (tours.response.data) { // if (tours.response) {
      // if tours.response.data is a type string, then convert it to json object
      // setListOfTours(JSON.parse(tours.response.data));
      setListOfTours(tours.response.data);
      // setListOfTours(tours.response);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
}

  useEffect(() => {
    getAllTours();
  }, [getAllTours]);

  return (
    <div>
      {
        !listOfTours
          ? // loading div
          : <div className="tourDisplay">
          {listOfTours.length > 0 && listOfTours.map((tour) => {
            return (
              <div>
                <div>Tourname: {tour.tour_name}</div>
                <div>...other values</div>
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </div>
      }
    </div>
  );
```

If this doesn't work, please inspect the browser and go to the network tab, and then make sure the API worked properly.

[image]

Comment: tours.response.data = https://pastebin.com/Ft11q7iF, tours.response = pastebin.com/sQwu3m4X, in the networking tab it says status code 200. So date comes in but somehow .map won't use the data

Comment: @Broump Just updated my answer. It seems you should set the response data from `tours.response` actually without data. e.g. `setListOfTours(tours.response);`

Comment: @Broump Please let me know my answer worked for you.

Comment: I mean technically it should work but now I'm getting the same error again. I there another way to accomplish the same result?

Comment: @Broump, Maybe the response data is a string not a json object, so please try to console.log(typeof tour.response.data). If it is an array then my answer should work, otherwise you need to convert the response.data to json object like `JSON.parse(response.data)`

Comment: The problem was that my backend put the same data twice in the response, so I had "] [" in the middle and it couldn't be JSON. That was such a frustrating journey! Thank you so much!! Have a nice day!

Comment: @Broump, Sounds good! Same to you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know is your `response.data` array or not but if it is array I can write down some solutions and you can try all of them

## Check is array empty or not

as I can read in your code you check is your array `true` or `false` , which is wrong because javscript never reads array inside, you can try it on your own `[] == []` is false so every time when you fetch data you keep your state empty because your if statement always returns **false** best way to check is array empty or not you can check its length

##### wrong

```js
if (tours.response.data) { //it always returns false
    setListOfTours(tours.response.data);
}
```

and also will be better if you check is your response data `undefined` or not

##### better

```js
if (tours.response.data.length > 0 || !tours.response.data === undefined) {
    setListOfTours(tours.response.data);
}
```

## Set default value before fetch

when you fetch data your state is always `[]` empty array and it never can read inside value if you will try to print in console `listOfTours.tour_date` you will get **cannot read properties of null (reading 'tour_date')** so before fetching the data create empty object with strins something like that

```js
const defaultState = {
  "tour_date": "",
  "tour_distance": 0,
  "tour_duration": 0,
  "tour_elevation_down": 0,
  "tour_elevation_up": 0,
  "tour_name": "",
  "tour_sport": ""
}

const [listOfTours, setListOfTours] = useState([defaultState]);
```

and that code will relax your react and won't to pop up error, what I mentioned in start of null property

and you can make simple ternary operator to do not `.map()` elements if you state has default value

```js
!listOfTours[0].tour_date === "" ?
listOfTours.map(each => {
   return <div>...</div>
}) : null
```

## Spread Operator

the last way to fix that issue I don't think it will work but I will include that one too, if your response is really array and react can't recognize it you can you spread operator

```js
if (tours.response.data.length > 0 || !tours.response.data === undefined) {
      setListOfTours([...tours.response.data]);
}
```

this code will put all the object in you array and it will update the state

If some of them will work let me know