# TypeError: weatherData.map is not a function

Tags: reactjs, fetch

I'm trying to map over data from API, but while writing the code to display the data I got this error: `TypeError: weatherData.map is not a function`

I tried removing useEffect from the code and tried to add curly brackets: `const [weatherData, setWeatherData] = useState([{}])`

**Update**: Line 14 log undefined : `console.log(weatherData.response)`

```
import axios from 'axios'
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import './App.css'

function App() {
  const [search, setSearch] = useState("london")
  const [weatherData, setWeatherData] = useState([])



  const getWeatherData = async () => {
    try {
      const weatherData = await axios.get(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${search}&appid={APIKEY}`);
      console.log(weatherData.response);
      if (weatherData) {
        setWeatherData(weatherData);
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getWeatherData()
  }, [getWeatherData])

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setSearch(e.target.value)
  }


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className='inputContainer'>
        <input className='searchInput' type="text" onChange={handleChange} />
      </div>
      {weatherData.map((weather) => {
        return (
          <div>
            <h1>{weather.name}, {weather.country}</h1>
          </div>
        )
      })}
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["TypeError: listOfTours.map is not a function" while trying to display fetched data in react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70200653/typeerror-listoftours-map-is-not-a-function-while-trying-to-display-fetched-d)

Comment: you should add dependecy `[]` to `useEffect` and should check response data.

Comment: Can you please log `res.data` and show what does it return? I'm almost sure that it's returning `undefined` (the server always takes some time to provide a response) and the reason why you get this issue is because you're trying to `.map` the result (`undefined`) before you actually set the state (an actual array). You have to create a promise function where you're calling the API - and preferably a conditional render based to display the information.

Comment: @SriVineeth didn't work

Comment: @DanielL I tried to log `res.data` and tried to create a promise function but they didn't fix it

Comment: @mohdh34m Can you update your code here and show how you're implementing the promise function?

Comment: I see there is a typo in your API key string interpolation. You missed the $ for APIKEY. Try `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${search}&appid=${APIKEY}`, and I see you have neither imported it nor declared the APIKEY variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're having errors in fetching the data as well as rendering it.

**Just change the entire App component  like this  :**

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
function App() {
  const [search, setSearch] = useState("London");
  const [weatherData, setWeatherData] = useState([]);
  const APIKEY = "pass your api key here";

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const result = await axios(
        `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${search}&appid=${APIKEY}`
      );

      setWeatherData(result.data);
    };

    fetchData();
  }, [search]);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setSearch(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="inputContainer">
        <input className="searchInput" type="text" onChange={handleChange} />
      </div>
      <h1>
        {" "}
        {weatherData.name} ,{" "}
        {weatherData.sys ? <span>{weatherData.sys.country}</span> : ""}{" "}
      </h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

this should be working fine just make sure to change  :  `const APIKEY = "pass your api key ";` to `const APIKEY = "<your API key> ";`

**this is a demo in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/combobox-material-demo-forked-z1fwmr?file=/demo.js:0-932)**

Comment: @mohdh34m Hope it solves your problem and let me know if you didn't get something in  this code

Answer (score 0):

Create a promise function:

```
const getWeatherData = async () => {
  try {
    
    const weatherData = await axios.get(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${search}&appid={APIKEY}`);
    console.log(weatherData.response);

    if (weatherData.response.data) { 
        setWeatherData(weatherData.response.data);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
}
```

Then call it.

Comment: This Line log undefined: `console.log(weatherData.response)`